# C++:Instalar biblioteca externa en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando instalar la biblioteca FreeImage usando Dev-C++ en Windows 10, pongo los archivos .h en la carpeta donde corresponde y agrego los directorios en dev C++, los archivos .DLL los pongo en la carpeta `C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin` que esta donde tengo instalado el Dev-C++ y un archivo .lib lo pongo en la siguiente carpeta `C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib` que tambien esta donde esta instalado C++.

A la hora de compilar el codigo los archivos .h los encuentra correctamente pero me lanza errores de tipo
`Undefined reference to` , Tengo entendido que es porque C++ no encuentra donde estan definidas las funciones.

Codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <FreeImagePlus.h>

int main(){
    fipImage img;
    img.load("Goten.jpg");


    return 0;
}
```

Errores:

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjljTTu.o    Aburrido2.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8fipImageC1E15FREE_IMAGE_TYPEjjj'
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjljTTu.o    Aburrido2.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8fipImage4loadEPKci'
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjljTTu.o    Aburrido2.cpp:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8fipImageD1Ev'
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjljTTu.o    Aburrido2.cpp:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8fipImageD1Ev'
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Programacion\collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Linker:

```
-static-libgcc  -lFreeImage
```

¿que me falta hacer?

Comment: También necesitas -lFreeImagePlus. Nota, poner bibliotecas en dentro de tu directorios del compilador/sistema NO es buena idea. Funcionará pero es muy difícil de administrar. Ponlos en un directorio separado y añadelo a tu configuración de DEV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si aún no lo has hecho, debes hacer el `include` correspondiente, teniendo en cuenta que si has puesto la biblioteca en el directorio estándar del compilador, deberás hacerlo con los símbolos de mayor y menor, mientras que sino, entre comillas dobles.

```
#include <bibioteca>    // La biblioteca está en el directorio estándar
#include "biblioteca"   // La biblioteca está en un directorio externo
```

Si esto no funciona, asegúrate de que tu IDE llame al compilador adecuado, ya que al intentar compilar código C++ con un compilador de C, en muchas ocasiones salta este error de referencia no definida.

Un ejemplo sería utilizar `gcc` para compilar programas en C y `g++` para compilar programas en C++, si tu IDE utiliza MinGW, o bien los compiladores de GNU.

En la ventanita de opciones/preferencias puedes especificar a qué compilador se llama al pulsar el botón de compilar. Si tienes MinGW instalado, tendrás `gcc.exe` y `g++.exe` en el directorio `C:\MinGW\bin\`.

Comment: Al incluir la biblioteca todo bien, el problema es al hacer uso de funciones de dicha biblioteca, ya que me lanza el error especificado en la pregunta

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta que FreeImage es para la version 4.4.0 de MinGW GCC y yo tengo la 4.9.2, gracias por la ayuda